# Pro Rata Split between accounts SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been asked to create a report that splits payments out between several accounts. The payment comes in against the Primary Account. I then need to split it on a pro rata basis based on the refered Balance.

Sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProRataSplit](
    [CustomerNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccountNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Account] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ReferredBalance] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [Payment] [FLOAT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Above is an example of how I have the data.

Here is some sample data to populate the table

```
INSERT 
INTO  tblProRataSplit(CustomerNo, AccountNo, Account, ReferredBalance, Payment)
VALUES     (75053894,3400266,'PRI',19449.56,150.00)
INSERT 
INTO  tblProRataSplit(CustomerNo, AccountNo, Account, ReferredBalance, Payment)
VALUES     (75053894,3443903,'MRGE',928.42,0.00)
INSERT 
INTO  tblProRataSplit(CustomerNo, AccountNo, Account, ReferredBalance, Payment)
VALUES     (75053894,3494492,'MRGE',14286.55,0.00)
INSERT 
INTO  tblProRataSplit(CustomerNo, AccountNo, Account, ReferredBalance, Payment)
VALUES     (75053894,3494714,'MRGE',912.81,0.00)
INSERT 
INTO  tblProRataSplit(CustomerNo, AccountNo, Account, ReferredBalance, Payment)
VALUES     (75053894,3495910,'MRGE',13613.23,0.00)
```

As you can see the 150.00 payment is registered against the PRI account. I need to split that £150 payment so that it is split between the 5 accounts pro rata against the balance (not evenly split).

I am at a bit off a loss here. If I havent been clear please let me know and I will provide more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; with cte as
(
    select  p.CustomerNo, p.AccountNo, p.Account, p.Payment, 
        m.ReferredBalance,
        pymt = round(m.ReferredBalance * p.Payment / sum(m.ReferredBalance) over (partition by p.CustomerNo), 2),
        rn  = row_number() over (partition by p.CustomerNo order by m.ReferredBalance desc)
    from    tblProRataSplit p
        inner join tblProRataSplit m    on  p.CustomerNo    = m.CustomerNo
    where   p.Account   = 'PRI'
    -- and  m.Account   = 'MRGE'
)
select  *,
    mrge_pymt   = c.pymt
            + case  when rn = 1 then c.Payment - sum(pymt) over (partition by CustomerNo)
                else 0
                end
from    cte c
```

If you do need to update back the table , you will need another level of CTE

Comment: This is really really close but it appears to omit the Primary account, so that it is splitting the payment between the 4 MRGE but ignoring the PRI??

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted?

Comment: remove the condition "m.Account = 'MRGE'" and it will consider the PRI